# What is the best way to get the paths of all the files located in a GCS bucket from Spark in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

So let's say I have a GCS bucket ID, something like - `gs://uhg802p0on/test_data`. How can I fetch all the paths of files located in this bucket from Spark in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Hadoop FS API [`listFiles`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-boolean-) method you can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val gcsBucket = new Path("gs://uhg802p0on/test_data")
val filesIter = gcsBucket.getFileSystem(conf).listFiles(gcsBucket, true)

var files = Seq[Path]()
while (filesIter.hasNext) {
    files = files :+ filesIter.next().getPath
}
```

`listFiles` with option `recursive=true` lists all the files recursively under the gcs folder.

If you want only paths without recursivity then you can use [`globStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) method.